# MYSQL SELECT statement with variable based on PHP for loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Currently, $selection outputs the following: MIN(Bale_ID), MIN(Incoming_Moisture) which is exactly what it should be outputting (they're names from another table). However, when I put $selection into the mysql_query $data1, it seems to just be reading the last value (MIN(Incoming_Moisture)) and only displays the results for that. How do I get the query to read the entire array of elements in $selection? Thank you!!

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($fieldnames1)) {   
$fields = $row1['fields1']; 
$explode = explode(',',$fields);

if ($row1) {
    for ($i=0; $i<$minrows; $i++) {
        if ($i<$minrows-1){
            $comma = ", ";
        }
        else {
            $comma = "";
        }
        //$selection = "MIN(".$explode[$i].")".$comma;
        //echo $selection;
        $data1 = mysql_query("SELECT MIN(".$explode[$i].")".$comma." from data WHERE (fchmitimestamp LIKE CONCAT(@year,'%',@month,'%',@day,'_________'))");
        $all1 = mysql_num_fields($data1); //return # of columns; for some reason is returning "1" right now.

        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($data1)) {
            for ($col=0; $col<$all1; $col++) {
                echo $all1;
                echo "<td>Min: " . $row2[$col] . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }       
}
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: if your storing a comma delimited string in the db, the structure is wrong

Comment: I'm teaching myself php and mysql as I go through this project, so I'm not sure what the correct structure is. Any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps you should get the hang of the idea what you are trying to achieve. Write down what problem you are trying to solve with this program (like you would describe it to a stranger) - thats called analysis and also gets your head together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are running the query once per for loop cycle (1 field at a time) and since first ones yields in SQL error because of the trailin comma, these will not be echoed except the last one.

```
-- notice the error in first query
SELECT MIN(Bale_ID), from data WHERE (fchmitimestamp LIKE CONCAT(@year,'%',@month,'%',@day,'_________'))
SELECT MIN(Incoming_Moisture) from data WHERE (fchmitimestamp LIKE CONCAT(@year,'%',@month,'%',@day,'_________'))
```

use `var_dump($selection)` instead of `echo $selection` to see yourself

Comment: This was it!!!! Got it!!!! Oh my gosh, if we were all in the same place I'd buy you all ice cream. So glad to get that done.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the order of operations in your code:

```
loop {
     ... fetch data ...
     ... assign results to $data1 ...
}
```

Nowhere in your loop do you output or save the results you've got in `$data1`, so each iteration of the loop overwrites the results of the previous iteration - in other words, only the LAST iteration's results will be stored.

Comment: That makes sense, so i've been playing with it more... do you have any suggestion of how to alter my code to fix that?

Comment: Move the second while loop inside the first loop, so that right after you get your `$data1` result, you start processing it immediately.

Comment: I actually just did that -- but the problem remains. $all1 is outputting 1, which is a problem. Also, even if I increase $all1 to a number larger than 1 in the last for statement, the output is blank while it should really have a value from my query.

Comment: Ok - i've updated the code with a couple of changes... moved the last while statement and such. Have the same problems, though.

Comment: It couldn't ever BE anything other than 1. You pull out a field, run a query, pull out another field, run a brand new query, etc... You only ever fetch one field at a time.